# Add new page in access vba dynamically created report

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using Access and VBA to create a dynamic report and I want to add a new page.
The code used until now looks like this:

```
Dim rpt As Report ' hold report object
Set rpt = CreateReport
With rpt
    .Visible = True
    .caption = "Calendar View"
    .BorderStyle = 1
    .AutoCenter = True
    .ScrollBars = 0
    .Printer.Orientation = acPRORLandscape
    .Modal = True
    .PopUp = True
    .AutoResize = True
    .FitToPage = True
End With

do until condition
    /* add controls and other stuff */
    rpt.Section(acDetail).ForceNewPage = 2
loop
DoCmd.Close acReport, strName, acSaveYes
```

How can I add new pages at the end of loop?
Thank you!

Comment: Does this report show multiple records (like a continuous form), or a single record, or is it filled only by VBA (i.e. has no recordsource)?

Comment: The report is generated only using VBA, and it's showing some records, the loop is actually dealing with a DAO recordset

Comment: Hm, seems my options were not sufficient. I meant: does the report have a recordsource? If yes, all you can do is add dummy records to that until a new page is reached. If no, there is a `PageBreak` object that you can add with something like `CreateReportControl "yourReport", acPageBreak, acDetail, Top:=yourCurrentY`

Comment: Ok, I managed to add a recordsource for the report, and now it shows 3 pages, the actual number of records, but all the controls repeat on every page.. how can I have the labels and controls on each page for the specified record?

Comment: I am creating controls like this: Set lineCtrl = CreateReportControl(frm.Name, acLine, acDetail, , , calendarLeft, calendarTop, calendarWidth, 1)
How can I change the acDetail to the corresponding record?